# Передать значение чекбокс с пробелом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! проблема такая как передать значение чекбокса если это значение с пробелом :

> *пример мне нужно получить* **images word**, *а я получаю*
>   **images**
>   Ниже пример кода
>
> ```js
> $(document).ready(function() {
>     $("button#renameSubmit").bind("click", function show() {
>             var  pathUpload = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val();
>             alert(pathUpload);
>
>       });
> });
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <form>
> <input type="checkbox" id="pathUpload" name="pathUpload[]" value="images">
>
> <span class="text-folder">images word</span>
> <br/>
> <button type="button" id="renameSubmit" value="1">отправить</button>
> </form>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У чекбокса есть аттрибут value, его вы и получаете.

Вариант 1: поменять аттрибут

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button#renameSubmit").bind("click", function show() {
            var  pathUpload = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val();
            alert(pathUpload);

      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="pathUpload" name="pathUpload[]" value="images word">

<span class="text-folder">images word</span>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="renameSubmit" value="1">отправить</button>
</form>
```

Вариант 2: доставать текст

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button#renameSubmit").bind("click", function show() {
            var  pathUpload = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').next('span').text();
            alert(pathUpload);

      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="pathUpload" name="pathUpload[]" value="images">

<span class="text-folder">images word</span>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="renameSubmit" value="1">отправить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых:
надо вместо `$().bind()` использовать `$().on()`.

У вас же jQ 2.1.1

А во-вторых:
зачем вам в обработчике именованная функция?

```
 ... function show() ...
```

можно заменить просто на

```
 ... function() ...
```

И в-третьих:

```
var  pathUpload = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val();
```

должно получить значение из атрибута `value` этого поля. Этот атрибут отсутствует.
Можно получить содержимое элемента `<span>` таким образом:

```
var  pathUpload = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').next().text();
```